# angular 4 reactive forms with material 2, disabling autocomplete

Tags: angular4-forms

I'm using angular cli, angular 4 and angular material 2. I need to disable chrome autocomplete, but I'm not being able to do so.

I already searched and found out that I need to add autocomplete=off or autocomplete=false both in the form and the input. I've also found a workaround by adding type="search". None of them seems to work.

Is material or angular overrinding this instructions?

I'm using reactive forms!

Any sugestions?

Thanks in advance by your help

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet!

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately no! But it's no longer an issue

Comment: And now, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Chrome no longer supports **autocomplete="off"** (Chrome stopped supporting this in 34.0). Instead, use **autocomplete="new-password"** instead.
You can check out Mozilla's documentation on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

From the documentation:

> For this reason, many modern browsers do not support  autocomplete="off" for login fields:
>
> If a site sets autocomplete="off" for username and password input
>   fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and
>   if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next
>   time the user visits the page. This is the behavior in Firefox (since
>   version 38), Google Chrome (since 34), and Internet Explorer (since
>   version 11).
>
> If an author would like to prevent the autofilling of password fields
>   in user management pages where a user can specify a new password for
>   someone other than themself, autocomplete="new-password" should be
>   specified, though support for this has not been implemented in all
>   browsers yet.

Example:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="filter.editorType==='text'">
    <input matInput autocomplete="new-password"
    [formControlName]="filter.id" 
    [placeholder]="filter.name" 
    (keyup.enter)="onApplyFiltersKeyboard()">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the attribute `autocomplete` to something else

[image]