# For Angular material , Disable autofill or autocomplete suggestion for an input?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm just using simple input containers such as this

```
<mat-form-field >
                    <input matInput placeholder=" Old Password"  autocomplete ="off" formControlName="OldPassword" [type]="hideOldPassword ? 'password' : 'text'" >

<button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hideOldPassword = !hideOldPassword" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hideOldPassword">
<mat-icon>{{hideOldPassword ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
</button>
<mat-hint align="end">Enter the Old Password</mat-hint>
<mat-error *ngIf="hasError('OldPassword', 'required')">OldPassword is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I need already saved password not show in the input field. I'm using autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="false". but not disabled.
Please suggest any answer

Answer (score 2):

As of V34 Chrome does not support `autocomplete="off"`.
Instead you should use `autocomplete="new-password"`.
For mozilla I am not sure. You can refer to documentation.

```
<mat-form-field >
<input matInput placeholder=" Old Password"  autocomplete ="new-password"  formControlName="OldPassword" [type]="hideOldPassword ? 'password' : 'text'" >
```

For more details refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010470/angular-4-reactive-forms-with-material-2-disabling-autocomplete).

Comment: @Afmed  i refer this link. i change autocomplete="new-password" . But, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

For angular

`<input [(ngModal)]="password" name="password" [attr.type]="password.length < 1 ? 'text': 'password'" />`

Don't use input type attribute.

---

Input type matters. ***[password]***

Not only chrome all the browsers will suggest Password suggestion based on input type only

When it detects with `<input id="passId" type="password"/>`

### **It will work 100% and working perfectly for me **

*Its important to remove `type="password"`*

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after trying all of the options above and not being able to clear my form of the pesky autofill I had decided to think outside of the box and come up with another option. So heres what I did and it worked:

```
import {Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked} from '@angular/core';

...

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

    registration = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl(''),
        password: new FormControl('')
    });

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        // email needs to be replaced to whatever field you want cleared
        this.registration.controls.email.setValue('');
    }

}
```

And if you want to clear the entire form you can do:

```
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.registration.reset();
}
```

If you have any questions please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use  `name` attribute. You don't need to `disable` or `off` the `autocomplete` attribute in this case. It worked for me like this (Using question's input field):

```
<input matInput name="new-password" placeholder="Old Password" formControlName="OldPassword" [type]="hideOldPassword ? 'password' : 'text'" >
```

Here you can see I have used `name="new-password"` and it will successfully disable the autocomplete. I was facing issue with google chrome where it kept showing the auto-complete passwords.

Hope it'll help.

Cheers!